# Jquery load overlap other page element

Tags: jquery, load, overlapping

In an html page I have a div element which will be populated from another file when the page is loaded.

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function()
 {
   $( "#index_articles" ).load( "./index-data.txt" );
 });

 <div id="index_articles"></div>

 <b> DUMMY LINES: only for mark the end of loaded data </b>
```

When the page is ready the file `index-data.txt` is loaded into the `index_articles` div.
Of course loading data from file will cause the div `index_articles` to increase it's height dimension.

What I expect is that the elemente of the page below the `index_articles` div will be repositioned at the end of the modified div, while what I have is that the div `index_articles` overlaps the other elements.

What I have missing in this code ?

I'm using jquery 1.8 and firefox 14.0.1 on fedora 17

Comment: There is no reason not to just include that content with the html to begin with.

Comment: It sounds like a `css` issue.  Are you using `position:absolute` and/or some `z-index` properties on the `index_articles` element or its containers?

Comment: As @Lix says, your issue very likely is with `CSS` - can you provide your `CSS` style for the div element that has the overlapping issue?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in css as suggested by Lix and Peter but was found in the parameter height:

```
  height: 70px;
```

After I remove the height parameter the text inside index_articles didn't more overlap the other components.

```
#index_articles {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: small;
  text-indent:1em;
   color: green; 
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

The question now is : why if I set the height parameter , it seems that this will block the reference for the other components in the dom page ?